# How to prove a function is convex?

Tags: convex-hulls

if $V=L^p(S,\Bbb R)$ and $g \in V$, how to prove f is convex for {$f \in V : f \geq g, \mu - a.e.$}?

I understand A is convex if $x,y,\in A, (1-a)x+ay\in A$ and $0<a<1$
Do I have to prove $x,y\in S, f((1-a)x+ay)\leq(1-a)f(x)+af(y)$?

Comment: Yes, usually this is exactly what you have to show. But I am not sure how convexity is defined for functions in $L^p$ as you cannot talk about the value of $f$ at some specific point.

Comment: What does $\mu-a.e.$ mean? And you wrote "if $\{\cdots\}$", but $\{\cdots\}$ is a set and no condition.

Comment: Almost everywhere with respect to the measure $\mu$?